# Htaccess, redirecting to pretty url

Tags: .htaccess, url, rewriting

I started looking into Htaccess today and tried it out. What i'm trying to achieve is that whenever you visit localhost/index.php, it'll redirect you to the "pretty" URL (in this case: localhost/home).

This is my Htaccess file at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I know that what i'm currently doing only rewrites /home to /index.php but I couldn't figure out how to do the opposite too..

Help would be appericiated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following conditions and rule (commented to explain):

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

# Check that the request is for `index.php`
# prevent infinite looping:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200

# If the conditions match, redirect to `/home`:
RewriteRule ^ /home [R=302,L,NE]

# Serve `index.php` for requests made to `/home`
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I can still access the index.php file without being redirected. Rewriting /home works though besides, my settings are set in right

Comment: Strange indeed - I can't think of any reason why it would do that.

Comment: For sure, I thought of sending every single request (being made) to the header.php (which is included on every single document) and then validate what he's requesting for and then redirect him to the "pretty" URL.

Comment: That's quite tedious, though. The code should just be working. I wonder if it will work if you disable MultiViews... try adding `Options -Multiviews` right at the top. (It's really just a wild guess, though.)

Comment: True, but can't seem to solve the problem using another way. Using Options -Multiviews doesn't seem to be working neither.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new redirect rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(home|index\.php)[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php|home)$ / [NC,R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Could you explain me what you're doing over here? I understand most of it but unfortenately not all :(

Comment: The condition checks `THE_REQUEST` (that is, the original request, which does not change on internal rewriting, thus preventing loops) to see if it contains `/index.php`. If so, redirect that request to `/home` with the status code `302` (used for temporary redirects). Then, rewrite requests made to `/home` to `index.php`.

Comment: @MikeRockett Thank you for the explanation, the code he sent doesn't work though..

Comment: @Bilal075 - I have just tested it on my server, and it does indeed work. Is that the entire content of your `.htaccess` file now?

Comment: @MikeRockett Yes it is, just copied the whole code he posted, but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: @Bilal075 - perhaps try with mine? If not, then your server may not configured properly for rewriting.

Comment: @anubhava It worked, thanks! By the way, how am I able to vaildate multiple requests at the time? For example: if request equals index.php && /home then redirect.

Comment: @anubhava - please would you explain why your previous answer (as well as mine) did not work? Is it a server-specific issue?

Comment: @MikeRockett: Yes I can explain. It didn't work because OP had kept these rules in a subdirectory under `DocumentRoot`. That's why `\s/+index\.php[?\s]` didn't work but `/index\.php[?\s]` worked.

Comment: @anubhava For example visiting www.domain.com/home & www.domain.com/index.php will both be redirected to www.domain.com

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.